# best BSD distro for Desktop PCs?

Tags: freebsd, bsd

I want to know if the bsd distros are for the desktop usage at all

If yes; What is the Best bsd distro for desktop usage some thing like ubuntu linux which is easy to use and good GUI management instead of command line system management

Comment: doesn't belong here. What has GUI management to do with programming??

Comment: "Best distro" is an extremely subjective question, not well-suited for a Q&A site like this one. Beyond that, it has nothing to do with programming, the [stated focus](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) of this site.

Answer (score 2):

Like Code Gray said : "Best distro" is an extremely subjective question.

However, FreeBSD has certainly the largest community in terms of number of users and ports. I think that you could try it.

In addition, there is a system based on FreeBSD named [PCBSD](http://www.pcbsd.org/) :

> PC-BSD is a free operating system with
>   ease of use in mind. Like any modern
>   system, you can listen to your
>   favorite music, watch your movies,
>   work with office documents and install
>   your favorite applications with a
>   setup wizard at a click.

My answer is very subjective, but I think it may help you.

Comment: Standard response: Look around. Use what the majority in your inmediate neighborhood uses, you'll be calling on them for help. If none, widen your net to user fora, official webpages and help; check out mailing lists for friendliness/competence/activity (there are places where just noobs hang out, swapping noob suggestions, be careful). Get LiveCDs and try them out on your machine(s). Check if the software you need is available as official packages.